# "A successful Billing Agreement has already been created for this token."

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

I'm trying to set up recurring payments with [Payum Bundle](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle) in Symfony. There needs to be the possibility for multiple recurring payments in one order and judging by the Paypal Sandbox dashboard, since the `PROFILE_START_DATE` is `DATE_ATOM` the initial payments go through, even if there are multiple items but when I look in Phpmyadmin, only one entry for `RecurringPaymentDetails` will have `"ACK": "Success"` and the rest will fail with `A successful Billing Agreement has already been created for this token.`

I have an OrderController which handles the logic, it sets the values of an entity that extends `ArrayObject`

```
/**
 * @Route("/accounts/order/paypal/completed", name="order_paypal_completed")
 */
public function orderPaypalCompletedAction(Request $request)
{
    $token = $this->get('payum')->getHttpRequestVerifier()->verify($request);

    $identity = $token->getDetails();
    $payment = $this->get('payum')->getStorage($identity->getClass())->find($identity);

    $gateway = $this->get('payum')->getGateway($token->getGatewayName());
    $gateway->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));

    $order = $payment->getOrder();

    if ($status->isCaptured() || $status->isAuthorized()) {
        $order->setStatus(Order::STATUS_COMPLETED);

        $agreement = $status->getModel();
        $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage(RecurringPaymentDetails::class);
        $payments = [];
        foreach ($order->getItems() as $item) {
          $payment = $storage->create();
          $payment['TOKEN'] = $agreement['TOKEN'];
          $payment['DESC'] = $agreement['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'];
          $payment['EMAIL'] = $agreement['EMAIL'];
          $payment['AMT'] = $item->getPrice();
          $payment['CURRENCYCODE'] = $order->getCurrency();
          $payment['BILLINGFREQUENCY'] = $item->getDuration();
          $payment['PROFILESTARTDATE'] = date(DATE_ATOM);
          $payment['BILLINGPERIOD'] = Api::BILLINGPERIOD_DAY;

          $payments[] = $payment;
        }
        $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans('Payment has been successful.'));
    }

    if ($status->isPending()) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('Payment has been canceled.'));
    }

    if ($status->isFailed() || $status->isCanceled()) {
        $order->setStatus(Order::STATUS_CANCELED);
        $this->addFlash('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('Payment has been canceled.'));
    }
    foreach ($payments as $payment) {
      $gateway->execute(new CreateRecurringPaymentProfile($payment));
      $gateway->execute(new Sync($payment));
      $recurringPaymentStatus = new GetHumanStatus($payment);
      $gateway->execute($recurringPaymentStatus);
    }

    try {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('An error occurred when saving object.'));
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

With this, I feel like, if there can only be one token returned from paypal, I'd have to redirect them back to Paypal for each item which is nonsense. Is there a way I can duplicate the token for each item or what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I find [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/792) so apparently I have to redirect them to Paypal for each subscription. A bit arduous but it's the only way apparently.

Edit: I spoke to soon, that issue pertains to different types of billing agreements in the same checkout, mine is for multiple billing agreements with the same conditions.